# How to get clickable status of imageButton on android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imagebutton, clickable

```
btnCall.setClickable(false);
```

I use this code for set but i wanna get its.

Who know answer please suggest me ?

Comment: Learn to [Accept Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) If the answer did not help, then comment with the problem! Accept my answer if it was useful..

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get clickable status of `ImageButton`:

```
    ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myButton.setClickable(false);

    // if clickable is false
    if (myButton.isClickable() == false) {
        Log.i("MyButton", "Clickable is false");
        // do your things here
        ...
    }

    // if clickable is true
    if (myButton.isClickable() == true) {
        Log.i("MyButton", "Clickable is true");
        // do your things here
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for android, since you have mentioned in your title !

If you want to know if an `ImageButton` is clickable or not use..

```
boolean status = btnCall.isClickable(); // will return true if its clickable, false otherwise
```